# Check whether all nodes in a particular Level are selected in Telerik RadtreeControl using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, treeview, radtreeview

Is there a way we could check whether all the nodes in a particular Level of a Telerik RadTreeControl are Selected using C# code(preferably LINQ)

I am using the the below code to get the Value for the Checked nodes in Level 1

```
selectedValues = string.Join(",", radTree.CheckedNodes.Where(node => node.Level == 1).Select(node => node.Value).ToArray());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping through the nodes, checking their level and what their Checked property returns:

```
    List<RadTreeNode> lvlOneNodes = RadTreeView1.GetAllNodes().Where(node => node.Level == 1).ToList();
    foreach (RadTreeNode item in lvlOneNodes)
    {
        Response.Write(item.Checked);
    }
```